# Visual Studio 2022 add icon to toolbar

Tags: visual-studio, icons

With my new laptop, I installed the community version of Visual Studio 2022. However, the icons that are normally present to comment and uncomment code are not there. In my attempt to add the two icons (using the keyboard method is too clunky), I cannot seem to add them to the toolbar. where they would normally be. (not on the menu bar) What are the precise steps of adding predefined visual studio icons, in my specific instance, the comment and uncomment icons?

I seem to be close with the adding and deleting of buttons.  I am able to find the comment and uncomment icons, but cannot get them to stick to the toolbar.